# How to make a very simple workflow for client A to approve his workers edited , new page and upload of new images?

Tags: workflow

SharePoint 2013.
Not very familiar with workfliws and tried many solutions off the web.
The best Inhad gotten was for the client to receive an email when the uodater woudlnworkmformy create a new page or edit.
But the the thkng is, the page woud go sttaght to publish despite it.
When thr client period view the tasks that approve and reject buttons at grayed out.

All tney want is to be abke to approve or decline an edits or new page or image before it is published.

How do you do this?
It looks so convoluted.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SOunds like you just need to enable content approval from the library's advanced settings.

Comment: Hello PirateEric, that sounds great but how do Inleg the approvera know I need sometjjg approved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PirateEric said, you should open the library's Advanced Settings and [enable content approval](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825239). If you want automatic emails to be sent to a static person or group every time a page is created or edited, then the easiest solution would be to make a workflow tied to the page library that runs whenever an item is added or edited. In the workflow, add a condition to check if the Content Approval status is "Pending" and if so, send the email.

[You can do more complex approval processes with the built-in approval workflow](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Use-a-workflow-to-manage-content-approval-for-a--library-2f7d3091-5f5f-43cb-bfd6-1ba8f5552eaf), but from what you've said I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for your time but how do you have it so that when she's ready and finished to have it approved then she can - but at the moment as soon as she creates a new page with nothing yet in it, a notification for approval is sent making the approver see work that hasn't been even started it ready to be reviewed.

Comment: Mike, you should use SharePoint's built-in approval workflow for that.

Comment: Hello Aron, but how do I configure it so that the approved only gets an alert when the page is "ready" to be approved and not just automatically approved as soon as an item is created or in the beginning of an edit? It seems either no notification at all or a premature one?

Comment: It depends on how your editors will indicate that a page is "ready". You could have them manually start the approval/notification workflow rather than relying on it automatically starting. Or you could require them to check it out when they're editing and only check it in when they're ready for approval.